# How to do file system difference through program or script?

Tags: java

Assume that we have a one-root file structure

```
repository
    |
    |---com
    |    |
    |    |---google
    |    |     |
    |    |     |---cloud
    |    |     |     |
    |    |    ...   ...
    |    |---github
    |    |     |
    |    |    ...
    |   ...
    |---org
    |    |
    |    |---spring
    |    |     |
    |    |     |---boot
    |    |     |    |
    |    |     |   ...
    |    |     |---cloud
    |    |     |    |
    |    |     |   ...
    |    |    ...
    |   ...
   ...
```

Just call it `folder A` to represent the root [repository] and [its structure]

Now make a copy for folder A, and rename `folder B`.

Folder B has the same structure as folder A, that means they all have folder com,org;

in sub-folder com, they all have folder google,github; ... ;

and in the bottom folder, they have the same file

Now things have some changed, a process puts some new folder and file at folder A, such as

`com/google/cloud/google-cloud-bom/0.146.0/google-cloud-bom-0.146.0.pom`

which different from the existing structure

`com/google/cloud.google-cloud-bom/0.141.0/google-cloud-bom-0.141.0.pom`

and also new structure in root

`io/minio/minio/8.5.1/minio-8.5.1.jar`

I don't know how many files, folders, sub-folders have been added in folder A, but I would like to threw the duplicate file and empty folder to catch them. In above case, the target folder C would be like

```
repository
    |
    |---com
    |    |
    |    |---google
    |          |
    |          |---cloud
    |                |
    |                |---google-cloud-bom
    |                            |
    |                            |---0.146.0
    |                                   |
    |                                   |---google-cloud-bom-0.146.0.pom
    |---io
        |
        |---minio
              |
              |---minio
                    |
                    |---8.5.1
                          |
                          |---minio-8.5.1.jar
```

How to operate the file system through powershell/java/python/others to achieve this function?

Comment: Can you control that writing process?

Comment: In general I suggest to make a list of files (including subfolders) ordered alphabetically: `/a/b/a.txt, /a/b/b.txt /a/c/c.txt` Compare the lists and find the diffs. Do you have any specific issue with an algorithm written in any particular programming language?

Comment: Is this a one-off process, or something you need to automate?  If it's a one-off I'd use WinMerge which will tell you the dfference between the folders.   If you want to script it, check out `rdiff` - https://serverfault.com/questions/39534/best-way-to-compare-diff-a-full-directory-structure   If you need to do it regularly, could you use a version control system (like `git`) and get it to do it for you?

Comment: the write process can't be controlled(at leaset i don't know how to control it), acutally I want to make this diff func working as fast as possible

Comment: Perhaps utilizing Java's [Watch Service API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#name) may be of some use. This could at least potentially let you know when changes are made which can then be acted upon.